# ScheduleViewer Google Maps JavaScript API error: ExpiredKeyMapError

Tags: general-transit-feed-specification

I'm trying to validate a GTFS file with [ScheduleViewer](https://github.com/google/transitfeed/wiki/ScheduleViewer), but it gives me an error:

```
js?key=AIzaSyBLmKxIq4izZzlXKPeVoAiURcT6z6ynobg&sensor=false:51 Google Maps JavaScript API error: ExpiredKeyMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#expired-key-map-error
_.Oc @ js?key=AIzaSyBLmKxIq4izZzlXKPeVoAiURcT6z6ynobg&sensor=false:51
```

I changed the API key, but the error is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment this is a bug in ScheduleViewer, the solution through [answerquest](https://github.com/google/transitfeed/issues/467) :

Hi I'd started seeing the problem from a couple days ago. Found out that passing in our own key in command line doesn't actually work : It was still using a key hard-coded in (And we were all using somebody else's key this entire time!!).

So if you have your own google maps API key (I'm not sure about usage limits and all but mine works for now), here's what to do:

Open gtfsscheduleviewer/files/index.html code
Find the